# Why does Windows Explorer collapse to "This PC"?

Tags: windows-explorer

When I use Windows Explorer I really want to see in the left pane where I'm at.
For this reason I have checked the "Expand to open folder" and "Show all folders" boxes in the Folder Options.

This has always worked well. But lately I notice that sometimes after a while when I return to Windows Explorer from another app, the left pane has collapsed to "This PC". This is **very** annoying IMHO, because I often have to get to the next folder which is then deep into some tree.

Can I do something about this, or is it a new bug?

Edit:

When I start WE and go to a certain folder it looks like this

[image: this]

So far so good. This is how I want to see it.

But then, after some time, it automagically alters to something like this
[image: this]

The left pane has now collapsed and is pointing to "This PC". If I want to go from one folder to another within the same project I have to open the whole tree again.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Are you on Windows 10 or 11 ?

Comment: I'm on Windows 10

Comment: (PS, thanks for the edit, Rohit Gupta. )